# What is the point of using implicitly unwrapped optional in this example?

Tags: ios, swift, initializer, failable

This is from the docs, section [Failable Initializers for Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203):

```
class Product {

     let name: String!
     init?(name: String) {
           self.name = name
           if name.isEmpty { return nil }
     }
}


if let bowTie = Product(name: "") {
   // no need to check if bowTie.name == nil
   print("The product's name is \(bowTie.name)")
}
```

This is described like:

> In the example above, the name property of the Product class is
>   defined as having an implicitly unwrapped optional string type
>   (String!). Because it is of an optional type, this means that the name
>   property has a default value of nil before it is assigned a specific
>   value during initialization. This default value of nil in turn means
>   that all of the properties introduced by the Product class have a
>   valid initial value. As a result, the failable initializer for Product
>   can trigger an initialization failure at the start of the initializer
>   if it is passed an empty string, before assigning a specific value to
>   the name property within the initializer.

Take a look at the last sentence:

> As a result, the failable initializer for Product
>   can trigger an initialization failure at the start of the initializer
>   if it is passed an empty string, before assigning a specific value to
>   the name property within the initializer.

This can't be seen from the provided code . In the provided code, it can be seen that assignment has occurred before `return nil` part, and either String (non-optional) or String? (optional) would work.

Another thing is that in provided example, it make no sense to use an implicitly unwrapped optional if it is defined as constant. Constants have to be initialized to default values right before the init is finished.

Any thoughts on this, or does anybody see the reason not to file a radar about this? Maybe I am missing something ? I have an idea actually why is implicitly unwrapped optional used in here, but it is a bad example. For me, this would make more sense:

```
class Product {

    var name: String! //let is changed to var

    init?(name: String) {

       if name.isEmpty { return nil } //Check here if passed value is non-empty
       self.name = name
    }
}
```

This way, a initialization failure can be triggered before the any assignment to the `name` property.

Comment: Note that with you last example, Swift will complain (compile time error) that the property `name` has not been initialised prior to returning `nil` from a failable initialiser. <-- EDIT: no longer after your edit of `name` to a mutable :)

Comment: @dfri Are you sure ? Name is declared as var (and implicitly unwrapped optional) so it will work.

Comment: @Whirlwind Note my edit to the comment: It regarded your example prior to you changing `name` from immutable to mutable.

Comment: @dfri Yeah, yeah. I know :) I haven't noticed an edit immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your concerns about misleading documentation are right.

Also, please note that in Swift 2.2 returning early from a failable initializer **does work**, even before all properties are initialized:

```
class Product {
    let name: String
    init?(name: String) {
        if name.isEmpty { return nil }
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Another change is that `deinit` is **not called** any more when returning nil from the failable initializer.

From Xcode 7.3 beta 2 [Release Notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.3_beta_2/Xcode_7.3_beta_2_v2_Release_Notes.pdf):

> Inside a class, a designated initializer that is either failable (`init?()`) or throwing (`init() throws`) is allowed to exit before initializing all stored properties and calling `super.init()`. This behavior is supported, making designated initializers more consistent with convenience initializers. Convenience initializers can also fail before performing a `self.init()` delegation.

Comment: For some reason, it seems as if the latter statement here (early return) is not true in Swift 2.1 for classes containing implicitly unwrapped optional properties that are _immutables_ (strange?). But this will be OK in Swift 2.2? (E.g., try an early return where you have a `let foo: String!` property in the class)

Comment: I was referring to the special case of implicitly unwrapped optional properties (as discussed by the OP), e.g. `let name: String!` (note the `!`).

Comment: Ah, we misunderstood each other, probably my bad for confusingly editing my first comment. I'm using XCode 7.2 and Swift 2.1, so my question regarded Swift 2.1.

Comment: Sorry I edited this by mistake, I wanted to edit my answer.

Comment: The reason why in Swift 2.1 using an implicitly unwrapped optional with `let` does not work is because the compiler can in this case not imply a nil initialized property (as `let` can be set only once).

Comment: Thanks , I didn't know about that fact that stored properties doesn't have to be initialized before early return in Swift 2.2